# SQL How to set Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

I have a user that needs to have read only access to a limited set of tables in a database. When I remove db_owner from their properties the access to the database goes away. This same user has read/write over two other tables on the server. How do I set the limited database to the right permissions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? @alcor8

Comment: Please check my revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the user to the [db_datareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629(SQL.90).aspx) role. You can do that in one of two ways, either through the [management studio](https://www.itsupportguides.com/server-side-tips/sql-management-studio-how-to-create-read-only-users/), or you can do something like this.

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',alcor8
```

Comment: ===================================

The database XXXXXX is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.DatabaseNavigableItem.get_CanGetChildren()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)

Comment: Are you using the ```sa``` account? Are you sure the user you're trying to grant permissions from has permissions to do that?

Comment: Figured it out. Leaving db_owner with db_reader and denying select on all unnecessary tables worked.

Comment: Please don't do it this way (that is, grant db_owner and then deny permissions); figure out why the user can't access the database without the db_owner role. The first step I'd take is to make sure that they are actually a user in the database. Do a select sys.database_principals and sys.database_permissions to see what they have.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `GRANT SELECT on [databasename].* TO '[name]';`

That should work if you have problems please post in the comments

Comment: Tried this but I can't open the database after taking away db_owner on the membership page under preferences from the admin login. On the owned schemas page that user has a box instead of a check on db_owner. Not sure what that means.

Comment: look dogs do not answer questions :P